# Question about two-sided limits

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is for example, say I have that

$f(x) =   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      1+x & x< -1 \\
      \frac{x^2}{2} & x\geq -1 \\
\end{array} 
\right. $

and I want to calculate 
$$\lim_{x\to0^-} f(x)$$ and $$\lim_{x\to0^+} f(x)$$,

Would I not just be calculating $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x^2}{2}$$ basically, since whether $x$ is approaching from the left or right of $0$, our function is $\frac{x^2}{2}$?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You only deal with that branch of the function since $0$ is an internal point of $(-1,+\infty)$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, since $0$ is only in the domain of $x^2/2$ as opposed to the function changing at $0$

Comment: thank you both very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. The situation would be different if you were trying to find the limit as $x$ approaches $-1$. You would use $1+x$ to find the left-handed limit, and you would use $\frac{x^2}{2}$ to find the right-handed limit.